# How to sign XML with SHA256 & X.509 correctly?

Tags: c#, xml, x509, sha256, xml-signature

I want to sign a XML with SHA256 by using a self-signed X.509 certificate. I was inspired by many articles in Stackoverflow and use this code:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
foreach (X509Certificate2 cert2 in store.Certificates)
{
    if (cert2.Subject == "CN=TestCerificate")
    {
        cert = cert2;
        break;
    }
}

store.Close();

CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
var exportedKeyMaterial = cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24));
key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.Load("test.xml");

SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
signedXml.SigningKey = key;
signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

Reference reference = new Reference();
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
reference.Uri = "";
reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"; 
signedXml.AddReference(reference);

KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
signedXml.ComputeSignature();

doc.Save("testSig.xml");
```

Afterwards, the generated signed XML part of "testSig.xml" looks like this:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>ghOEPeYtAUs5Kb8VMOCIS3f2wIY=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>HANI0GrICbyc5tlmvtU9cB7txdxtuY4uDsntp5XVzaRQbts76ff3Qg==</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
```

As you can see the XML says that "SHA1" was used to sign the XML instead (see nodes "SignatureMethod" & "DigestMethod"). But I would expect, that the SHA256-URLs have to be stated in these nodes. Is this assumption correct? If yes, does anybody know how to solve this problem? I use C# 4.6.0.

With best regards,
Michael

Comment: Your code as written builds the signature but doesn't put it into the document (is it pre-signed?).  You're missing the call to `GetXml()` and inserting that node into document.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to solve my problem. In fact, I forgot to add the signed XML-Node to my xml file. The "wrong" signed xml part from above came from another code snippet which was executed accidently. So I had two mistakes merged together. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you successfully called `signedXml.ComputeSignature()` that just does the computation, it doesn't insert a signature element into the document (the XmlDocument you pass in the constructor is just what document `GetXml()`'s node will parent to).

You need to call `signedXml.GetXml()` (after `ComputeSignature`) to get the computed `ds:Signature` element, then insert that into your document.

The fact that your document has a signature node already in it is confusing.  My first thought was that `test.xml` already had that signature in it, but your comment says that it was just some oops code from elsewhere. Lesson learned, I guess :).